# SQL: Grouptext, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is an sql statement and an error I'm receiving.  I want to group all returned items by the `prodID`.

Error:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted,
>   except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Statement:

```
 SELECT TOP 20 
         PRODID, ITEMDES
         FROM orderedItems oi
         left join orders o on  oi.order_id = o.order_id
    Group by PRODID, ITEMDES
```

Comment: ITEMDES is a text field in the DB

Comment: What type of field is ITEMDES?

Comment: I only want items to be grouped by proid, however i need the field ITEMDESout too but I don't want to really order by this field.

Comment: If you are on Sql Server 2005 or newer you might use varchar(max) instead of TEXT.

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović  I just changed ITEMDES to varchar(MAX) and got the same error

Comment: sounds like `TOP 20` is the problem - as a test please delete that bit and try the query

Comment: There might be some other error - see [this Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f2bf/2) for demonstration that you can group by `varchar(max)`.

Comment: Are your PRODID, Order_ID columns type int? They are the only other columns being sorted or compared.

Comment: You select TOP 20 but don't add ORDER BY. Do you know that your query can output different results from time to time?

Comment: Please show data in the tables and expected results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they can't. Additionally, they're deprecated in favour of `(n)varchar(max)` types.

If you need to group them, either change your data structure from `(n)text` to `(n)varchar(max)` or do a convert in your group clause

```
 GROUP BY ProdID, CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ItemDes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If ITEMDES is a TEXT or blob you can avoid GROUP BY with [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select TOP 20 * from 
(

SELECT 
         PRODID,ITEMDES,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PRODID order by o.order_id) rn
         FROM orderedItems oi
         left join orders o on  oi.order_id = o.order_id
) as t 
where rn=1
order by PRODID; -- any order here you wish
```